# Cannot send email using nademailer which says "this.newTransport(...).sendMail is not a function" in Email Class

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, email, nodemailer

I have created an Email class to send email to my client but can't send email instead it shows this message in postman:

> "this.newTransport(...).sendMail is not a function"

It worked well without converting it to class, but after converting it is not working. Please help me solve this problem. Here is my code:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const pug = require('pug');
const htmlToText = require('html-to-text');

module.exports = class Email {
  constructor(user, url) {
    this.to = user.email;
    this.firstname = user.name.split(' ')[0];
    this.url = url;
    this.from = `Carrie White <${process.env.EMAIL_FROM}>`;
  }

  async newTransport() {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      // sendgrid
      return 1;
    }

    return nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: process.env.EMAIL_HOST,
      port: process.env.EMAIL_PORT,
      auth: {
        user: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME,
        pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD
      },
      tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
      }
    });
  }

  // Send the actual email
  async send(template, subject) {
    // 1) Render html based on a pug template
    const html = pug.renderFile(
      `${__dirname}/../views/emails/${template}.pug`,
      {
        firstname: this.firstname,
        url: this.url,
        subject
      }
    );

    // 2) Define email options
    const mailOptions = {
      from: this.from,
      to: this.to,
      subject,
      html,
      text: htmlToText.htmlToText(html)
    };

    // 3) Create a transport and send email
    await this.newTransport().sendMail(mailOptions);
  }

  async sendWelcome() {
    await this.send('welcome', 'Welcome to the Natours Family!');
  }
};
```

and in my sign up function this code is used like this:

```
const url = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/me`;
  console.log(url);
  await new Email(newUser, url).sendWelcome();
```